# Assigning a function to an object in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and have been learning from [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#statistical-transformations). Recently, I've come over some code in stats_summary where a function is defined as another function, such as

```
fun.min = min,
fun.max = max,
fun = median
```

In these cases, the summary functions (`fun.min`, `fun.max`, `fun`) are being defined as the base R functions (`min`, `max`, `median`). I thought this was really interesting and wanted to learn more about assigning functions to other functions/variables, however I couldn't find anything about it. How common is this seen in R, where a function such as `fun.min` is defined as a different function such as `min`? Furthermore, when we define objects with functions, why do we not have parentheses after the function, such as `fun.min = min()`, since this gives me the error, `argument "x" is missing, with no default`?

Comment: When you put parentheses after a function in R, you are calling the function. Without parentheses, you are referring to the function object itself. This is very common in R. I'm not sure what a good answer would look like here, but it's unlikely to be better than a good introductory text to R.

Comment: Also see e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html